# Why insert some unwanted values in database

Tags: php, mysql

after I wrote the following php script:

```
<?php

include_once ('C:\Users\fabio.gatta\OneDrive - Accenture\MySite\moduli\simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'https://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/summer/1896/ATH/';
$tagname_h1 = 'h1';
$tagname_tr = 'tr  class=""';


    $olympiad = array();
    $html = file_get_html($url,true);
    foreach($html->find($tagname_h1) as $tag) {
        $olympiad[] = trim($tag->innertext);
    }


    $result_oly=explode(" ",$olympiad[0]);

    $year = $result_oly[3];
    $city = $result_oly[4];
    $season = $result_oly[5];
    $sport = $result_oly[0];

//Prendo le informazioni dei vincitori

    $athletes = array();
    $country = array();

    foreach($html->find($tagname_tr) as $tag)
    {
        foreach($tag->find('td') as $td)
        {
            $a_tags = $td->find('a');
           $img_tags = $td->find('img');

            if(count($a_tags) ==0)
            {
                $ath ="";
            }
            elseif(count($a_tags)==1)
            {               
                $ath = $a_tags[0]->innertext;


            }
            else
            {
                $ath = array();
                foreach($a_tags as $a)
                {
                    $ath[] = $a->innertext;

                }
            }
            $athletes[] = $ath;

            if(count($img_tags) ==0)
            {
                $coun ="";
            }
            elseif(count($img_tags)==1)
            {               
                $coun = $img_tags[0]->alt;

            }
            else
            {
                $coun = array();
                foreach($img_tags as $alt)
                {
                    $coun[] = $alt->alt;

                }
            }

            $country[] = $coun;         
        }

        $medals = ["gold", "silver", "bronze"];

foreach ($athletes as $key => $values) {

    if (strpos($values,"'s ") > 0){

        $gender="";
        $event="";

        list($gender,$event)=explode("'s ",$values);
    }   

           //connessione al database

       $link = mysqli_connect('192.168.0.97', 'root', 'admin','Olympics');
        if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
         }
            echo 'Connected successfully'. '<br>';

     //prendo gli ori
      if ($key == 1){

        if (count($values) == 1){

         $ath_key = $athletes[$key];
         $country_key = $country[$key];
         $medals_key = $medals[$key-1];

         mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO MedalResults (Year,City,Season,Sport,Event,Athlete,Gender,Country,Medal) VALUES ('$year', '$city', '$season', '$sport', '$event', '$ath_key',' $gender', '$country_key', '$medals_key')");

        }

        elseif (count($values) > 1){

            foreach($values as $sub_key => $sub_values){

                $ath_key = $athletes[$sub_key+1];
                $country_key = $country[$sub_key+1];
                $medals_key = $medals[$key-1];

              mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO MedalResults (Year,City,Season,Sport,Event,Athlete,Gender,Country,Medal) VALUES ('$year', '$city', '$season', '$sport', '$event', '$ath_key',' $gender', '$country_key', '$medals_key')");

        }
        }
       }

       //prendo gli argenti

       if ($key == 2){

        if (count($values) == 1){

          $ath_key = $athletes[$key];
         $country_key = $country[$key];
         $medals_key = $medals[$key-1];     

         mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO MedalResults (Year,City,Season,Sport,Event,Athlete,Gender,Country,Medal) VALUES ('$year', '$city', '$season', '$sport', '$event', '$ath_key',' $gender', '$country_key', '$medals_key')");

        }

        elseif (count($values) > 1){

            foreach($values as $sub_key => $sub_values){

             $ath_key = $athletes[$key];
            $country_key = $country[$key];
            $medals_key = $medals[$key-1];


             mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO MedalResults (Year,City,Season,Sport,Event,Athlete,Gender,Country,Medal) VALUES ('$year', '$city', '$season', '$sport', '$event', '$ath_key',' $gender', '$country_key', '$medals_key')");
        }
        }
       }

       //prendo i bronzi
       if ($key == 3){

        if (count($values) == 1){        

           $ath_key = $athletes[$key];
            $country_key = $country[$key];
            $medals_key = $medals[$key-1];

           mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO MedalResults (Year,City,Season,Sport,Event,Athlete,Gender,Country,Medal) VALUES ('$year', '$city', '$season', '$sport', '$event', '$ath_key',' $gender', '$country_key', '$medals_key')");

        }

        elseif (count($values) > 1){

            foreach($values as $sub_key => $sub_values){

             $ath_key = $athletes[$key];
            $country_key = $country[$key];
            $medals_key = $medals[$key-1];

             mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO MedalResults (Year,City,Season,Sport,Event,Athlete,Gender,Country,Medal) VALUES ('$year', '$city', '$season', '$sport', '$event', '$ath_key',' $gender', '$country_key', '$medals_key')");

            }
        }
       }

        mysqli_close($link);
  }

   unset($athletes);
   unset($country);

    }   

?>
```

In the database I have some unwanted rows like:

```
1896 Athina Summer Athletics 100 metres Tom Burke Men USA gold
1896 Athina Summer Athletics 100 metres Fritz Hofmann Men GER silver
1896 Athina Summer Athletics 100 metres Array Men Array bronze
1896 Athina Summer Athletics 100 metres Array Men Array bronze
```

Why do I get Array instead of athlete name and country name?

Second issue: some of the athlete and country array elements are null and thanks to if statement I think to exclude them, but I get still rows with athlete and country null. How avoid this?

Comment: well obviously(?) because the value is an array not a string

Comment: You could set restrictions on the two colomns athlete and county where you do not accept NULL or empty values.

Answer (score 0):

You get the string array instead of athlete name and country where more than one athlete has won the medal in the event. This is the case with the 1896 100m bronze where Alajos Szokoly and Frank Lane drew. Therefore, it is not *unwanted* data but complex data. In this case your code does not resolve to a specific element in the `$athletes` and `$country` arrays, so array is stored as a placeholder to denote more than one element within an array. The solution is to adapt your page scrape algorithm and either to breach the normalisation of your data strucutres and allow two atheletes to be stored in one array element or extend your storage algorithm and data structures to accommodate the extra complexity.

Comment: Yes, I found the way to get the info I need, thank you.